# Why is this check for prime numbers returning true on some non-prime numbers?

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with a function to check if a number is prime - it's returning that a number is prime when it isn't sometimes (even numbers sometimes, too!). Any idea why?

```
int isPrime(long x){
    int i;

    if(x==2||x==3)      return 1;   //if i = 2 or 3, return true
    if(!(x&1))          return 0;   //if x is even  return false

    for(i=3;i<=sqrt(x);i+=2) if (x%i == 0) return 0;        //if x is divisible by i return false

    return 1;
}
```

To everyone, thanks so much for the answers, I'd +1 them all if my rep was high enough :D

Sadly, my idiocy has reached new heights, and I found the error was within logic elsewhere in my program.

Comment: Could you give an example of some numbers that don't return the expected result?

Comment: did you by any chance pass a negative number as argument?

Comment: it seems 104760 was returned from it. I'm attempting the 7th Project Euler problem, to find the 10001st prime number. If you'd like to see the rest of the code, here's the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/7L3ymdt8

Those doing the Euler problems, don't look at it! =))

edit: that code takes out checking of even numbers, btw, since they're all prime. But the problem still remains.

Comment: In that case, look at prime sieve algorithms, your method, even when only checking until sqrt(x), does a lot of unnecessary calculations :)

Comment: Compiled with GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5, wrapped in a test loop: `for (long i = 5; i < 1000000; i++) if (isPrime(i)) printf("%ld\n", i);`, this produced 78,496 values. To check that they were all prime, I used `./prime_generator | xargs factor | grep ' .* '`, and every single result it produced was a prime. (Some other values that are prime might have been missed, but every value produced was prime.) On my machine, I can speed up `isPrime()` by using `int n = sqrt(x); for (i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)` for the controlling loop (consistently 0.354s vs 0.327s). I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I have no idea what's going on here. Maybe it's a logical error somewhere else in my code

Comment: http://ideone.com/e6EpzJ Works fine for 104730.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly it because of the rounding of the `sqrt(x)` as result of this function call is **floating point** value. So it can be a little less than rounded to the closest integer.

In this case e.g. `sqrt(25)` could be rounded to `4` instead of `5`.

**EDIT**

The fault number on `104730` tells that

```
 if(!(x&1)) return 0;   //if x is even  return false
```

doesn't seem to work correctly... So, can you try the `x&1L`?

I am not sure, but id the size of the `int` and `long` is different, and (probably) `1` is implicitly caste to a shorter one type, so possibly it checks incorrect bit...

Also try just

```
if(!(x%2)) return 0;   //if x is even  return false
```

in order to avoid bit patterns usage and platform dependence.

Comment: That's my thought as well. I'd check up to sqrt(x) + 1.

Comment: Or `ceil( sqrt( x ) )`. Implicit rounding is for chumps.

Comment: I've tried checking up to sqrt(x) + 1, and it still has some faulty returns. :(

Comment: @jaska can you provide one more example of the fault?

Comment: @icepack It seems like an platform dependent issue.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the for-loop to:

```
for(i=3;i<=x/2;i+=1) if (x%i == 0) return 0;
```

In the main i go through the first 100 Numbers.

```
int main()
{
    long test=0;
    int i = 2;
    for( ; i < 100; i++)
    {
        test = isPrime(i);
        if(test == 1) printf("%d ",i);
    }

       getchar();
       return 0;
}
```

This is the ouput:
and this ist the ouput for the first 100 primes:

```
2 3 5 7 11  13  17 19 23 29  31 37 41 43 47  53 59 61 67 71  73 79 83 89 97
```

I changed the `i+=2` to `i+=1`, because in your code the skip every second number.

Comment: The `sqrt()` and `i+=2` were used in order to avoid additional unnecessary calculations.

Answer (score -1):

You are not checking whether `x` is divisble by 2.

Before that `for` loop add a `return 0` if its is divisble by 2.

Comment: That's what  this is for:

    if (!(x&1)) return 0;